# JBoss Eclipse integration issue - old Jboss directory is loading

Tags: eclipse, jboss, server, jboss7.x

Every time when I **remove** my project from eclipse server config and **clean** and after restarting the eclipse my **old** JBOSS directory is getting loaded in server runtime env.(which I used long time back). This happens every time I open eclipse. Is there any eclipse config file which needs to be changed/deleted to avoid this.[image: Eclipse Server environment config]

Comment: Close eclipse so that metadata is saved. Check in the task manager when eclispse.exe has stopped, then restart Eclipse.

Comment: I usually make sure everything is closed properly. This time I made sure and when I checked the server config and again old server directory came back !

Comment: Is there a buildpath variable JBOSS_HOME in your Eclipse preferences?

Comment: No. There is not. But I have JBoss runtime detection in eclipse preference.

Comment: In your JBoss runtime detection, uncheck the Every start checkbox.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. It resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a runtime to JBoss Runtime Detection in Eclipse preferences, at every startup of Eclipse, these paths are scanned for available runtimes.

If the location is found valid, it is automatically added to the Server Runtime Environment. If you do not want it to show here, please remove the entry from Runtime Detection.

More details can be found [here](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.server.ui.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftwinstprf.html) and [here](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/latest/en/User_Guide/html/chap-JBoss_Server_Tools.html).

In such cases you should also check if some environment variable - say JBOSS_HOME in this case - has been set to a default value.